# array length count doesn't match

Tags: php, arrays

When i set a global array as this

```
 $items[$users[$clientID]['room']] = array("seat" => $seat, "item_id" => $q[1], "room" => $users[$clientID]['room']);
```

it is

```
  $items[4] = array("seat" => 20, "item_id" => 10, "room" => 4);
```

but when i do a count it telling the length of $items[4] is 3? It should only count 1 because i only have "1" item.

```
for ( $i=0;$i<count($items[$users[$clientID]['room']]);$i++):
    //something 
endfor;

print_r($items[$users[$clientID]['room']]);
```

outputs:

```
Array
( 
    [seat] => 43
    [item_id] => 46
    [room] => 5 
)
 COUNT 3
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What's about `count($items)`?

Comment: If the array containing three items then obviously it'll display count as 3

Answer (score 2):

You have defined $items[$users[$clientID]['room']] as one array: but an array that comprises three items - seat, item_id and room - and it is those individual array items that you are counting.

Answer (score 1):

`$items[$users[$clientID]['room']]` is an array and `count()` returns no of element in an array, if the value to count is not an array it will return 1. See this link for more information about `count` function.

[Count Function - PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Comment: Yes OK, so how can i then count the number of arrays in the array $items[.....] ?

Comment: You need to run an `foreach` loop and use `is_array` function.

Comment: $itemCount = count($items);

Comment: @MarkBaker It will not return the number of arrays, as it may possible that `$items` contains some non-array records.

Comment: $tmpItems = $items; $itemCount = count(array_filter($tmpItems,'is_array'));